# OWASP ZAP scan returns "Application Error Disclosure" to javascript library. Is it false positive? How to proove that or fix?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

After automatic scan with OWASP ZAP 2.8.0 I have "Application Error Disclosure" with javascript file (moxiejs library). Site is based on wordpress updated to the newest version. 
How to fix this vulnerabity? Or is it a false positive?

```
Medium (Medium) Application Error Disclosure
Description 
This page contains an error/warning message that may disclose sensitive information like the location of the file that produced the unhandled exception. This information can be used to launch further attacks against the web application. The alert could be a false positive if the error message is found inside a documentation page.

URL http://x.x.x.x/wordpress/wp-includes/js/plupload/moxie.min.js?ver=1.3.5
Method  GET
Evidence    Internal Server Error
Instances   1
Solution    
Review the source code of this page. Implement custom error pages. Consider implementing a mechanism to provide a unique error reference/identifier to the client (browser) while logging the details on the server side and not exposing them to the user.

Reference   
CWE Id  200
WASC Id 13
Source ID   3
```

[image]

I've found that moxiejs script contains string "Internal Server Error", example ( https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-includes/js/plupload/moxie.min.js ). Does ZAP checks by searching error text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this is false positive, because ZAP scanned a JS-URL which have keywords like `RuntimeError:` '500:Internal Server Error', that is why you got this false positive message.

Comment: For details of how to handle false positives in ZAP see https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQhandleFP